# Livewire hydrate issue corrupted data

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a problem with hydrate I got an error:

> Livewire encountered corrupt data when trying to hydrate the [product.product-base-info] component. Ensure that the [name, id, data] of the Livewire component wasn't tampered with between requests.

This error is givenwhen I'm second time hit method **toggleTranslationFields**

```
class ProductBaseInfo extends Component
{
    public array $translateFieldsList = [];

    private array $languages = [];

public function boot()
    {
        $this->translateFieldsList();
        $this->languages = config('translatable.locales');
    }

    protected function translateFieldsList()
    {
        $this->translateFieldsList['product_name_trans'] = false;
        $this->translateFieldsList['product_desc_trans'] = false;
    }

    public function mount(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->initListsProductGroups();
        $this->initListsProductCategories();
    }
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'product.*.name' => 'required|string|min:5',
            'product.*.description' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.product.product-base-info');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $this->product->created_by = Auth::id();
        $this->product->updated_by = Auth::id();
        $this->product->save();

        $this->emitUp('productAdded',
            ['productSaved' => true, 'product' => $this->product]);
    }

    public function toggleTranslationFields($field)
    {
        $this->translateFieldsList();
        $this->translateFieldsList[$field] = true;
    }
}
```

**With template:**

```
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="store">
        @csrf
        <div class="flex flex-row">
            <div class="basis-7/12 pr-2">
                <div>
                    <x-label-trans for="product-name" :value="__('labels.product.name')"/>
                    <div class="relative rounded-md  shadow-sm ">
                        <x-text-input-trans wire:model.defer="product.pl.name" id="product-name"/>
                        <x-text-input-globe wire:click="toggleTranslationFields('product_name_trans')"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <x-label-trans for="product-desc" :value="__('labels.product.desc')"/>
                    <div class="relative rounded-md shadow-sm ">
                        <x-textarea-trans wire:model.defer="product.pl.description"
                                          id="product-desc"/>
                        <x-textarea-globe wire:click="toggleTranslationFields('product_desc_trans')"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @foreach($this->languages as $language)
                    @if($language != 'pl')
                        {{$language}}
                        <div
                            class="product_name_trans
                            {{ $this->translateFieldsList['product_name_trans'] ? 'block' : 'hidden' }}">
                            <x-label-trans for="product-name-{{$language}}" :value="__('labels.product.name')"/>
                            <div class="relative rounded-md  shadow-sm ">
                                <x-text-input-trans wire:model.defer="product.{{$language}}.name"
                                                    id="product-name-{{$language}}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div
                            class="product-desc-trans
                             {{ $this->translateFieldsList['product_desc_trans'] ? 'block' :  'hidden' }}">
                            <x-label-trans for="product-desc-{{$language}}" :value="__('labels.product.desc')"/>
                            <div class="relative rounded-md shadow-sm ">
                                <x-textarea-trans wire:model.defer="product.{{$language}}.description"
                                                  id="product-desc-{{$language}}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-1">
            <x-button type="submit" right-icon="chevron-right" positive label="{{__('labels.Next')}}"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have try to debug but i'm to silly for that :(